# NextJS 13 APP routing - anti pattern - weird behavior

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm wondering if I am doing some leakage/incorrect practices in NextJS.

The functionality that I want to happen is

Comment is added via form -> Action is triggered on server -> new comment is added into db -> page is refreshed

It works, but if I change the code in page.tsx and add a single line at the top:

'use server';

I get an error saying you cant pass event listeners to functions... Which is really strange, I heard that all the components inside of the app directory are server by default.

Also, if I don't declare videos outside of the component:
`let video: Video | null = null;`

And instead declare the variable here

`(let) video = await videosDao.getVideoWithCommentsById(params.id);`

I'm getting strange errors upon hitting the submit button. What is going on?

app/page.tsx

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import videosDao from "@/dao/videos";
import commentsDao from "@/dao/comments";
import VideoPlayer from '@/components/VideoPlayer';
import CommentsSection from '@/components/CommentsSection';
import RelatedVideos from '@/components/RelatedVideos';
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import AddComment from "@/components/AddComment";
import { cookies, headers } from 'next/headers';
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import type { Video } from "@/types/Video";
import type { Comment } from "@/types/Comment";

interface Props {
  params: {
    id: string,
    name: string
  }
}


let video: Video | null = null;

const VideoPage: NextPage<Props> = async ({ params }) => {
  // Assume you have fetched video, comments, and related videos
  // pass them to their respective components as props

  if(!params.id) {
    redirect('/');
  }

  video = await videosDao.getVideoWithCommentsById(params.id);

  if(!video) {
    redirect('/');
  }

  const addComment = async (data: FormData) => {
    'use server';

    let headersList = headers();
    let ip = headersList.get('x-real-ip') ?? headersList.get('x-forwarded-for') ?? headersList.get('remote-addr');

    let commentContent = data.get('comment') as string;
    let nickname = data.get('nickname') as string;
    let videoId = params.id;
    let fingerprint = cookies().get('clientId')?.value;

    if(!commentContent || !nickname || !videoId || !fingerprint) {
      return false;
    }

    let comment: Partial<Comment> = {
      comment: commentContent,
      nickname: nickname,
      videoId: videoId,
      fingerprint: fingerprint,
      ip: ip ?? '',
    }

  
    try{
      let inserted = await commentsDao.insertComment(comment);
      if(!inserted) return false;

      video?.comments?.push(comment as Comment);
      revalidatePath(`/video/${videoId}/${video?.name}`);
    }catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

  }

  const relatedVideos = await videosDao.getRelatedVideos(video);

  return (
    <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4 mt-2 md:grid-cols-1">
      <div className="lg:col-span-3 justify-center">
        <VideoPlayer video={video} />
        <AddComment onAddComment={addComment}/>
        <CommentsSection comments={video.comments ? video.comments : []} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <RelatedVideos videos={relatedVideos} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default VideoPage;
```

app/components/AddComment.tsx

```
'use client';

import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface AddCommentProps {
  onAddComment: (data: FormData) => void;
}

const AddComment: React.FC<AddCommentProps> = ({ onAddComment }) => {
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('');
  const [nickname, setNickname] = useState('');

  console.log(onAddComment)
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row space-x-4 lg:w-11/12 md:w-full p-4 shadow rounded bg-gray-800">
      <form action={onAddComment} className="flex flex-row space-x-4 flex-grow">
        <div className="flex-1">......
```